# Passing User object in celery using django

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm currently editing the save method in one of my models, so that I can save who changed an object or created a new one.

Currently, its working fine when its ran in the main thread, but the save method is also used in different tasks through Celery. And when the save method is ran in a task `get user` returns `None`. To get a user i'm currently using [django-curser](https://github.com/Alir3z4/django-cuser) since this model is being used in different apps inside my Django project.

Is there a way to send the current user to celery? I've been told to use a context manager or a wrapper but im not sure how.

My save method is:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        from models import Log
        log_entry = Log()
        log_entry.object_id = self.id
        log_entry.object_repr = self
        user = CuserMiddleware.get_user()
        log_entry.user = user
        log_entry.content_type_id = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self).id
        log_entry.save()
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you run celery task with user_id in arguments, correct?

Comment: @KirillErmolov not really, my idea is to use a decorator or something similiar on top of the task to make it not intrusive (I dont want to modify the tasks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution with decorator:

I think you can use this decorator to add user in celery task

```
from functools import wraps


def append_user(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def __wrapper__(*args, **kwargs):
        user_login = kwargs.pop('user_login')
        CuserMiddleware.set_user(user_login)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return __wrapper__
```

And apply it to task this way

```
@task
@append_user
def celery_job():
    pass
```

Also for my celery task I use this decorator (to turn off all async jobs in settings)

```
def async_task(func):
    from django.conf import settings
    ALL_TASKS_IS_ASYNC = getattr(settings, 'ALL_TASKS_IS_ASYNC', True)

    @wraps(func)
    def __wrapper__(*args, **kwargs):
        async = kwargs.pop('async', ALL_TASKS_IS_ASYNC)
        if async:
            return func.delay(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return __wrapper__
```

And `celery_job = async_task(celery_job)` in `__init__.py` file

You can use the same idea to append `user_login` to all tasks

```
def async_task(func):
    from django.conf import settings
    ALL_TASKS_IS_ASYNC = getattr(settings, 'ALL_TASKS_IS_ASYNC', True)

    @wraps(func)
    def __wrapper__(*args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['user_login'] = CuserMiddleware.get_user().username
        async = kwargs.pop('async', ALL_TASKS_IS_ASYNC)
        if async:
            return func.delay(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return __wrapper__
```

### Edit:

I think this decorator may optimize refactoring:

```
def task_with_user_info(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def __wrapper__(*args, **kwargs):
        user = CuserMiddleware.get_user()
        kwargs['user_login'] = user.username
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    if getattr(func, 'delay', None):
        __wrapper__.delay = task_with_user_info(func.delay)
    return __wrapper__


@task_with_user_info
@task
@append_user
def celery_job():
    pass
```

After this changes you should able to use `celery_job` as usual.

Comment: thanks! Your answer makes a lot of sense, i'm trying to make it work but i'm getting an error in user_login = kwargs.pop('user_login') specially (KeyError('user_login',)), any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Did you run task this way `celery_job.delay( ... user_login='some_login')` ? or use `async_task`?

Comment: yup forgot to do that... is there a way to do this without having to pass the the user login in each task? Or will I have to change all of the celery_job.delay calls?

Comment: Yes, you have to pass user_login in task argument. Or use some decorator like `async_task` to optimize this work.

Comment: Added another variant of decorator, maybe it is more suitable to your task.

Comment: i'm getting 'function' object has no attribute 'delay' with the new decorator

Comment: Oh yes, need to use `if getattr(func, 'delay', None):` instead of `if func.delay:`

Comment: yup that did the trick!! The only small error im still getting is that after setting the user in the append_user decorator, the user is not setting correctly and afterwards when im retriving the user in my original save, the user is a unicode (username) and not the user object. But I guess thats a problem with the cuser library

Comment: Any clue why I might me getting this error when i'm trying to set the user with cuser?
`File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cuser/middleware.py", line 50, in set_user
    user = User.objects.get(username=user)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'objects'`